# Passive voice - I or me?

Tags: word-choice

I know this is incorrect:
John and me will be giving a birthday treat.

I know this is correct:
John and I will be giving a birthday treat.

But what when the voice is changed?
Birthday treat from John and I?
Birthday treat from John and me?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, can you please reconsider the "duplicate" mark? It only addressed one part, which I have specified I know. I want to know about the other part. It does not have any example that answers my question.

Comment: It is a duplicate to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me

Same title, but not the one you've marked

Comment: Yes, those are two different questions with exactly the same title. There's also [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/), [“Bob and I.” or “Bob and me.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257744/), [“I and someone”, “me and someone” or “I and someone we”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/), [“I and others” or “others and I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99941/), and doubtless many more. It really is a "hardy perennial" here on ELU.

Comment: Every single time, the rule of thumb is the same: Remove John from the equation and re-evaluate. "a birthday treat from I" is incorrect, and therefore "a birthday treat from John and I" is equally incorrect.